# Android - Auto Adding Items To ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

The code below currently pulls data from a mysql database and displays it in a ListView. What I am looking to do is find a way to have the application check the mysql database every minute or so to check for any new entries, and if it finds a new entry that isn't in the current ListView - it will prepend the new item(s) to the top of the list. I have read a few things on notifyDataSetChanged(), but I guess I can't grasp how it actually works or how to implement it. Any Help is appriciated. Thanks!

```
public class Data extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<Feed> posts = new ArrayList<Feed>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new FeedTask().execute();
    }
    private class FeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Data.this,"", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xxxx/livefeed/getdata.php");
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Feed feed = new Feed();
                    feed.content = json_data.getString("post");
                    feed.time = json_data.getString("post_time");
                    posts.add(feed);
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("ERROR", "Error loading JSON", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            setListAdapter(new FeedListAdaptor(Data.this, R.layout.feed, posts));
        }
    }
    private class FeedListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Feed> {
        private ArrayList<Feed> posts;
        public FeedListAdaptor(Context context,
        int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Feed> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.posts = items;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.feed, null);
            }
            Feed o = posts.get(position);
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
            tt.setText(o.content);
            bt.setText(o.time);
            return v;
        }
    }
    public class Feed {
        String content;
        String time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Call the notifyDataSetChanged() in onPostExecute method.

Comment: So, just by calling notiftyDataSetChanged() it will continuously check for new items in the database? For some reason I can't imagine it being that simple...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing everything in a local sql database after you parse the XML object. that way you can use [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) on a content provider and it gets updated asynchronously when something new gets added to the database.

Its probably going to take some refactoring of your current code but its worth it IMO because its pretty much what you are looking for